# Poor performance on bitnami server AWS EC2 micro

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm looking for some assistance with performance tools for Linux server running on AWS micro instance.

Apache serves web pages really slow. I have used `top` command and Idle value is almost 100% and stalling 0% so it looks like the CPU is not the problem. I want to make clear that it's the slow response from the server that is the problem, on site optimizing is not included in my question.

Server is running a regular LAMP stack and has a small OpenCart shop running. `Memory_limit` is set to `128mb`. My experience with EC2 micro is that it's not a problem to run a small server with limited use of SQL-queries on a micro-instance.

What debugging would you recommend me to continue with?

Im open to any ideas that I can try.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade, even temporarily, to to a better class of VM and see if it solves the problem. I gave up trying to use micro-instances for much of anything. I love EC2/AWS, but wouldn't consider using a micro instance.

Answer (score 0):

Micro instances have a cpu profile unlike any other instance type. It can burst up to 2 compute units, but outside of that burst its limited to 0.1 or so.

`top` also does not tell you the real cpu usage (due to effects of virtualization), you will need to look at cloudwatch for that.